# Query records by class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a class method for a product returning its average rating, how do I query products with average_rating greater than a param I receive from frontend?

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

def average_rating 
  ratings.sum(:rate) / ratings.count
end

end
```

For a scope I would need to pass the param from controller to model. Should I do that? Or should I just calculate the average rating in the controller instead? Or save average_rating in database with a callback when a rating is saved?

Comment: You can not use class methods inside ActiveRecord Query, you can use scopes if that fits your need. Also please add your average_rating method implementation to the question for better understanding.

Comment: The value I compare is a param I receive from a frontend. So I would need to pass it from controller to model. Which I understand should be avoided.

Comment: Method doesn't matter let say self.ratings.sum(:rate) / self.ratings.count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call class methods from SQL. You can however load all records into memory and do this, which is quite inefficient if you have a lot of records.

```rb
Product.all.select { |record| average_rating > record.value }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a ruby method you can't do it (with SQL), unless you move your "average" logic into SQL too.

If the amount of records is a small one of the simplest solution is to use Ruby.

`Product.all.select{|e| :&average_rating > e.value}`